# Getting second row from Rails scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  second = Trade.with_currency(currency).h24.order('id desc').limit(1).offset(1).try(:price)
  first = Trade.with_currency(currency).h24.order('id desc').first.try(:price)
```

I want to get the price of the first and the second row. The first one is working but I have problems to get the second row. With above query I get nil back.

when i do the query for the second row directly in mysql it is working:

```
SELECT `trades`.* FROM `trades` WHERE `trades`.`currency` = 5 AND (created_at > '2014-01-11 16:20:06') ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      prev = Trade.with_currency(currency).order('id desc').limit(1).offset(1).first.try(:price)
```

this is the solution - I added to select the first result offsetting by 1.

Comment: Could you please explain the changes you made? A brief explanation can often help the OP understand why the code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

with `offset(1)` add `first` in the statement

it will go like

```
  second = Trade.with_currency(currency).h24.order('id desc').limit(1).offset(1).first.try(:price)
```

Comment: that does not help. I get as soon as I add a limit or offset into the query an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the values:

```
Trade.with_currency(currency).h24.order('id desc').pluck(:price).first(2)
```

The `pluck` method fetches just the values and `first(2)` is used to pull the first two values.